# The objects in mobile build seems distorted

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a game in Unity 2020.3,13, and I first ran the game in Unity game window and all seems good, but when I try to run the game in my phone all the objects that a added seems wrong
[Game run in game in Unity game window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc2T7.png)
[Game run in my mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM7YC.png)

Comment: By "objects" do you mean your textures are fuzzy?  Unity defaults to using compressed textures at normal quality.  Select the texture and select "No Compression" for perfect quality or set a high quality on the compression.